# HTML Checking overflow - text position

Tags: javascript, html, slider, overflow

I made a sidebar with custom sliders and what I want to do is change the image of slider when the sidebar scrolled to top/bottom. I have a overflow:hidden but I don't know how to check if it's on the bottom or top.

[Website](http://nitidus-consto.kilu.org)

-- David

Answer (score 0):

It depends of course on how you implement your slider (The link you added doesn't work too well) but for example, if what changes when it's on the top is simply it's distance from the top of the div it's nested in then simply add a check whenever the slider finishes it's movement to check if the `top` or `botttom` CSS property is equal to 0, as done here:

```
if ((document.getElementById("myimage").style("top")==0) {
    document.getElementById("myimage").setAttribute("src","topImageSrc");
}

if ((document.getElementById("myimage").style("bottom")==0) {
    document.getElementById("myimage").setAttribute("src","bottomImageSrc");
}
```